# How to use element validation and form validation on the same form?

Tags: 7, forms

I have a custom form I am validating with a custom validation function like this:

```
…
$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
    '#validate' => array('custom_misc_form_validate'),
  );
```

This works as expected, my custom validation function is called, etc. But I would like to add an further form element to the form, which defines an element validation callback function, like this:

```
$form['email'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Email'),
      '#description' => 'Bitte geben Sie eine gültige E-Mail-Adresse an: An diese Adresse werden Ihnen die Zugangsdaten zu unserem Intranet zugesandt.',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#element_validate' => array('custom_misc_email_validate'),
      '#weight' => -998,
    );
```

The validation callback looks like this:

```
function custom_misc_email_validate($element, &$form_state, $form) {
  $value = $element['#value'];

  // Check if email has a valid format.
  if (!valid_email_address($value)) {
    form_error($element, t('The e-mail address %mail is not valid.', array('%mail' => $value)));

  // Check if email address is already registered.
  } elseif (user_load_by_mail($value)) {
    form_error($element, t('The e-mail address %email is already registered. <a href="@password">Have you forgotten your password?</a>', array('%email' => $value, '@password' => url('user/password'))));
  }
}
```

But the callback for the element validation is not called, as long as there is an callback in `#validate` of the submit button. As soon as the latter is commented out, the callback for the element validation is actually called, but `$element['#value']` is always empty.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You aren't doing anything wrong, but #element_validate is always executed, so I'm thinking you're misdiagnosing the issue.

Comment: @Jaypan Thank you for your estimation. I where misdiagnosing the issue. The problem was, that I accidentally called `drupal_get_form` twice on the form, which one shouldn't do and what had strange site effects.

Comment: I’m glad you figured it out!